# MVC - reading model variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to read model variable in jquery ready function.

```
 var jsNotes1 =@Model.Notes1;
```

when the model.notes1 has an integer value, I was having no issues.
But when the model.notes1 has a string value, say for ex: "abcd", the line is getting converted as below

```
var jsNotes1 = abcd
```

and Jquery is assuming abcd as a variable rather than as string value and is throwing reference error that abcd is not defined.

Please help me if i am missing something here

Comment: String values need to be wrapped in quotes...

Answer (score 3):

try to this

```
var jsNotes1 ='@Model.Notes1';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in quotes as it needs to be treated as a string, otherwise it's invalid JavaScript

```
var jsNotes = "@Model.Notes1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this is in javascript...

```
var jsNotes1= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.notes1));
```